# How do I configure the representation of an array of ObjectIds with BsonClassMap?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serialization, bson

Consider the following C# class:

```
public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Users { get; set; }
}
```

How do I configure that Users maps to an array of ObjectIds in MongoDB using `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Role>`? I am able to configure that the scalar property Id maps to an ObjectId, but can't figure out how to do the same for a sequence (array):

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Role>(m =>
    {
        m.MapIdProperty(r => r.Id).SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
        // How do I map r.Users to an array of ObjectId??
        m.MapProperty(r => r.Users);
     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to call `SetSerializationOptions` with a correctly initialized `ArraySerializationOptions` object:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Role>(m =>
    {
        m.MapIdProperty(r => r.Id).SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
        m.MapProperty(r => r.Users).SetSerializationOptions(
                new ArraySerializationOptions(new
                        RepresentationSerializationOptions(BsonType.ObjectId)));
     });
```